# Pdf rendering in blackberry

Tags: pdf, blackberry-jde

I am new to Blackberry Smartphone development. My application contains functionality of PDF book reader. I downloaded the full PDF from server but I don't know how to  view the PDF file.
Is there any library that will help me to view the PDF file? In-built attachment of PDF in email is shown in browser. I don't want to open it in browser. If any one knows about it then please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you give readers some ideas of what you've tried? That will help ensure ideas are in the direction that will work for your use case, as well as showing you've made an effort to solve the problem already.

Comment: @halfer thanks for your reply. as I had only google it on how I can do it. and downloading a PDF file is just same as downloading a simple file. Now my problem is how to view or render that PDF file in blackberry.